# How can I create chat app using react and nodeJS to use in different projects, like plugin or something?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, chat

I have to create react chat application with node js server and need it to be usable in different projects. How can I create it or deploy? I'm new in this field, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a chat app (UI + backend) is too complex to explain in one short answer.
However, it can be achieved in a few steps.

1. Create a user interface e.g as a CRA app.
2. Create server app e.g using socket.io
3. Create a widget that is loaded into an iframe
4. Load the widget on your site.

If you don't want to build a widget, you can make a chat UI as a complex component and import it directly into other projects.

**Useful resources (starting points)**:
More about widgets: [How to make a web widget](https://chatscope.io/blog/web-widgets-part-2-widget-him/).
Example loader builder: [Widgeton](https://chatscope.io/widgeton-beta/)
React chat components library: [React chat components](https://github.com/chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react)
React headless chat hook: [@chatscope/use-chat](https://github.com/chatscope/use-chat)
Websocket library: [Socket.io](https://socket.IO)